# Calculating the shortest distance between polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, distance, proximity

In QGIS 3.12 I need to calculate the shortest distance from the boundary of one polygon to the boundary lines of a set of polygons as shown in the image below

[image]

I have followed the instructions according to this question [Calculating shortest distance between multiple Polygon borders to a common Polygon border?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/257119/calculating-shortest-distance-between-multiple-polygon-borders-to-a-common-polyg).

It seemed to provide a good solution using the field calculator to generate a new feature in the attribute table (eg the attribute table of the blue polygons) using the following formula

```
distance($geometry, geom_from_wkt('Polygon ((........))'))
```

as described in the above link. However, when I randomly checked some of the distances using the measuring tool, while many of my tests were consistent, I found several that were incorrect e.g 196.11 km vs 216.9 km.

All the shapefiles and my project are in the same projection system.

I cannot figure out why there are the errors or if this is the best way to calculate these distances.

Ideally I would like tracklines generated to show the shortest distance, however this may be over complicated.

Comment: Have you had a look at `join by nearest`? If so, what does it lack?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If only length values are needed, please use the following expression in the ["Field Calculator"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#using-the-field-calculator)

```sql
length(
    shortest_line(
        $geometry,
        geometry(get_feature('building', 'osm_id', '1234567'))
        )
    )
```

In my example I am referring to a feature by its `"id"` from a certain layer, otherwise use [`geom_from_wkt()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#geom-from-wkt).

If new geometries have to be created, then try using the ["Geometry by expression"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) geoalgorithm from the QGIS's Processing Toolbox (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) with the following expression:

```sql
shortest_line(
    $geometry,
    geometry(get_feature('building', 'osm_id', '1234567'))
    )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much this looks wxactly what I am trying to do