# Shortest distance of point feature from one line in QGIS

Tags: qgis, distance, shortest-path, points-to-line

I would like to ask for your help with calculating in simple way distance of points feature to one line (for example, what is distance of cities from the national border).

I see there were few topics on this question but I did not manage to calculate it. I tried to use Distance to nearest hub (line to hub) but distances seem to go in the direction of center and not in the direction of the nearest distance.

Comment: Try join attributes by nearest from processing toolbox

Comment: Can be helpful: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/375054/calculating-the-shortest-distance-between-polygons-in-qgis/375062#375062

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to select your line using a different criterion, here I opt for the nearest.

To get the shortest distance between points and the (nearest) line feature, you can use the field calculator with this expression:

```sql
distance(
    $geometry,            -- the current point geometry
    overlay_nearest(
        'border',         -- the name of your line layer
        $geometry
    )[0]                  -- get the first feature from the array of nearest features
)
```

[image]

[image]

To get the distance to the nearest point on the boundary of a polygon:

```sql
distance(
    $geometry,
    boundary(                  -- get the boundary of the polygon as a line geometry
        overlay_nearest(       
            'polygon',
            $geometry          
        )[0]                   -- get the polygon nearest to the point
    ) 
)
```

[image]

*Note: lines and labels were created separately to visualise the result of the  expressions*

Get a specific feature using an attribute value:

```sql
distance(
    $geometry,
    boundary(
        geometry(
            get_feature(
                'countries',          -- layer name
                'NAME',               -- field name
                'Zambia'              -- attribute value
            )
        )
    )
) / 1000                              -- convert m to km
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot!